# Newsstand app: existing library for magazine format

Tags: ios, swipe, newsstand-kit

I'm building a newsstand app for ipad where the content of issue is the magazine format (Title detail in columns and pictures) where user can swipe horizontally whenever the content of article is longer, moreover during the swipe, app will scroll to the new article when we reach the last page of the current article. I just wanna know if there existing library to deal with the need I describe above. I appreciate all your suggestion.